# Loading two server certificates in SSL context

Tags: c, openssl

Is there a way to set more than one certificate as a device certificate in the SSL Context? I will be having two certificates signed by different trusted CA servers in server SSL. But client can validate only one of them. I am looking for a way to update the SSL context with two certs. I am planning to send both to the clientSSL and the client will check both of these and pick just one of them as server dev cert.

Comment: Do you intend to change the SSL handshake protocol? An ordinary browser won't be able to support it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just arbitrarily redefine TLS. The `Certificate` message only allows one certificate and its authentication chain. See RFC 2246 and successors.